# why use 'widget' in python callback function (Gtk) which only prints on stdout?

Tags: python, callback, gtk, pygobject, gobject-introspection

I am learning Gtk programming with python from [this](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html). But I can not understand what is the reason for the `widget` keyword in the following callback definition? Can someone please explain what it does?

```
def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
    print("Hello World")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the button is clicked, the on_button_clicked method is executed. When this happens, the window and button objects are passed to the method as `self` and `widget`, respectively. This is useful in cases where one needs to do something with the button, such as getting its state or changing its text.

Without the `widget` parameter, the button object would be passed to the method and there wouldn't be a parameter to receive it, and you would get a TypeError.

Comment: does that mean the instance of any object is always passed to all the callback functions which are called from that instance?

Comment: @DipanjanPatra Yes, that is why the first parameter of an object's method is always self.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with PyGObject; does it not provide a way to pass callback data (which would be a third parameter)?